# Concatenation in string query vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm doing a cascading combo box which is connected to mysql. Is it possible to concatenate the query to have a straight query. Please see code below. TIA

```
'connection
dbCon = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=kdi_forms;Uid=root;Pwd=MyNewPass")
strQuery = "SELECT prodName, prodCon FROM po_products WHERE prodCon =" & supply & ""
SQLCmd = New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
SQLCmd.CommandTimeout = 30

        'open query
        dbCon.Open()
        DR = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader

        While DR.Read

            Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(DR.Item("prodName"))

        End While

        'done
        DR.Close()
        dbCon.Close()`
```

Comment: concatenate the which query?

Comment: @SATSON - yes supply will contain a number for example `SELECT prodName, prodCon FROM po_products WHERE prodCon =" & supply & "` to `SELECT prodName, prodCon FROM po_products WHERE prodCon = 2 "`  is this possible?

Comment: Explain? because i did not understand want you want

Comment: In strQuery i want to use a straight query to display the result using `While DR.Read
            Me.ComboBox2.Items.Add(DR.Item("prodName"))
        End While`    but the value for prodCon with come from another combobox which will be "supply". If prodCon = supply display their products. is it possible to make concatenation in a strQuery? or insert a string in a query? if possible how? THANKS!

Comment: replace the procon combobox value in supply

Comment: You should use parameterized queries. Don't use string concatenation to create a query (this is vulnerable for SQL injections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, strQuery is just a string value.  And like all strings, it can be concatenated...  But as commented on your post already, the assumption is **supply** is an *integer* being passed from your comboBox and is and being selected from an *integer* field in the database.  If **supply** is not an *integer* field in the database, or more generally speaking, if the value of **supply** could be anything other than an *integer* then you need to add single quotes in your query like this:

prodCon ='" & supply & "'"

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem:

```
prodCon =" & supply & "
```

Try to replace it with this:

```
prodCon ='" & supply & "'
```